# Powering the Raspberry 3 B+ with PSU

Tags: pi-3b+, power-supply, usb-power

I have a PSU from Amazon that provides 5V and I used my trusty multimeter to adjust the voltage to exactly 5.0V. I used it previously to run some silent fans, but I don't have any use for that anymore now.. Time to see if I can use it for the Raspberry. It gets 5V through the charger and the PSU gives up to 5A..

Now when I read the schematics on https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/ for the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+, I can connect the Pin 1 of J1 (Power in, 5V-) through PP2 and Pin 5 (Power in, GND) with either PP3, PP4, PP5 or PP6.

I have soldered a small wire with a dupont connector to PP2 and PP3. However, when I attach the PSU to it, nothing happens. I have double checked - the Pi turns on with the regular charger and the wires are properly connected.

Can you give me any suggestions how to make this work?

Comment: Hi @Kat Seiko, Welcome and nice to meet you. (1) Can you use your trusty multi-meter to measure the voltage between PP2 (Ground) and PP3 (+5V, before polyfuse) ?

Comment: You might like to compare my photo with your wiring, to make sure you indeed have  soldered the wires correctly. :) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104596/rpi3b-micro-usb-connector-got-15v-power-is-it-dead-can-i-save-it.

Comment: Thanks. I have a feeling I'm too "young" to post images of my modifications.

Comment: No problem. Show your stuff when you get older.  I remember one day when I was young, I hesitated to show off my stuff. On second I thought, if I spend more time than others, I can share my experience.  And if I am going to show off something, say a photo, I would put in more effort to make a good photo, and when I can going to share my experience, I often discover that I actually don't understand that thing quiet well, can teaching actually help me understand and learn better, building up my confidence and improve my technical presentation skills, like photography, PhotoShop ect, ...

Comment: Sometimes after showing off my masterpieces, I found other better works, then I know how to improve myself.  This is an example:  
Powering Raspberry PI With Broken Micro USB Connector - 2019jan
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/76653/powering-raspberry-pi-with-broken-micro-usb-connector.

Comment: I often found others giving answers better then mine, and their answer is a pleasant surprise, because I can learn more things in that area. You question is an example, It is only read others' answers that I learn new skills. I usually followed the clever guys and traced back their other answers, give them upvotes, and learning from them at the same time. Rework Guru:
@crasic = https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/71180/crasic.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @tlfong01 and some further searching, I learned that there is such a thing as "technical" and "actual" voltage. The wires were placed correctly - the "problem" was just that the wires had to be switched around.. I initially didn't want to try that, fearing I might break something, but it turns out that my fears were unfounded.

Answer (score 1):

Use an USB cable and make a power line with it. Then put it in the power port of raspberry pi 3. To make such converter use a multimeter to detect the polarity then set up the whole thing. But my recommendation is to use a 3A PSU so that raspberry pi wouldn't fetch more power than it needs,